# HTTPConnection to make DELETE request: 505 response

Tags: python, http, version, httpconnection, http-status-code-505

Frustratingly I'm needing to develop something on Python 2.6.4, and need to send a delete request to a server that seems to only support http 1.1.  Here is my code:

```
httpConnection = httplib.HTTPConnection("localhost:9080")
httpConnection.request('DELETE', remainderURL)
httpResponse = httpConnection.getresponse()
```

The response code I then get is: 505 (HTTP version not supported)

I've tested sending a delete request via Firefox's RESTClient to the same URL and that works.

I can't use urllib2 because it doesn't support the DELETE request.  Is the HTTPConnection object http 1.0 only?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: HTTPConnection uses `HTTP/1.1` by default. [505](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.6) is a problem with the *server*, so *it* doesn't seem to support version HTTP/1.1.

Answer (score 1):

The `HTTPConnection` class uses HTTP/1.1 throughout, and the [505](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.6) seems to indicate it's the *server* that cannot handle HTTP/1.1 requests.

However, if you need to make `DELETE` requests, why not use the [Requests package](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) instead? A `DELETE` is as simple as:

```
import requests

requests.delete(url)
```

That won't magically solve your HTTP version mismatch, but you can enable verbose logging to figure out what is going on:

```
import sys
requests.delete(url, config=dict(verbose=sys.stderr))
```

Comment: Thanks, would like to use that, but would mean going through a lengthy open-source approval process with my company.  It's not a big tool I'm working on, just needs to make a couple of simple http interactions

Comment: @jurasic: You mean any puny little external library needs approval? I pity your company.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **urllib2**:

```
req = urllib2.Request(query_url)
req.get_method = lambda: 'DELETE'   # creates the delete method
url = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

httplib uses HTTP/1.1 (see HTTPConnection.putRequest method documentation).

Check httpResponse.version to see what version the server is using.